# C# received and wrote hashcode

Tags: c#, hash

I've created a program to receive a hash code of an .exe file.
And than with streamwriter I wrote it to an .exe file.
If I wanna open the .exe of it I get the error:
is not a valid win32 application.

What can I do with the hash and is it possible to create an .exe file from it that works.

Thank you very much!

```
byte[] hash;
using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Program files\CCleaner\CCleaner.exe"))
{
    hash = SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(stream);
}
string base64Hash = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
Console.WriteLine(base64Hash);

StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Win7\Desktop\Hash.exe");
myWriter.Write(base64Hash);
```

Comment: No, this is never going to work. What are you trying to do? Normally you would calculate a hash for a received file, and compare it to the known good hash for the file to check its integrity.

Comment: @Lee I wrote that if you get a hashcode, that you create a program from it. So I wanna test it

Comment: What are you expecting the program to do? Windows executables are usually [Portable executable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) files. The only way this could do anything is if your hash just happened to be a valid PE file.

Comment: @Lee I just wanna know if it is possible to "clone" a program with a hashcode

Comment: You want to know if the SHA-1 hash of an executable file is itself a valid PE file which does the same as the source program? No, that is not possible.

Comment: A hash code is not analogous to DNA. It's more like a fingerprint. You can't recreate a person from a fingerprint.

Answer (score 1):

The hash code of an executable is a string, not a valid executable. If you want to store the hash code, then write it to a text file, like this:

```
byte[] hash;
using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Program files\CCleaner\CCleaner.exe"))
{
    hash = SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(stream);
}
string base64Hash = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
Console.WriteLine(base64Hash);

StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Win7\Desktop\Hash.txt");
myWriter.Write(base64Hash);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error:

> I get the error: is not a valid win32 application

is that you are overwriting the beginning of the application. While you can *append* anything to most exe files, overwriting data is not going to work.

If you append the hash like this:

```
StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Win7\Desktop\Hash.exe", true);
```

the application should run normally. Within this application, you can access the last bytes of the exe file to retrieve the hash.

Comment: thanks, but I still get that error, but with the comments of Lee I got the feeling that it ain't possible to do what I wanted to do, what is cloning a program

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn what a [Hash Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) is. It cannot be used for what you intend. A hash cannot be reversed to get the original contents. That would be fantastic data compression.